# How to access the first element or number in counter using Python

Tags: python, collections

I want to access or select the first number in counter using Python. So I have this code, that will run random number from 1 to 10 with 100 trials, then it will count the most frequent number that occured.

```
from collections import Counter
from random import choice

y = []
for x in [(choice([i for i in range(1,10) if i not in [0]])) for j in range(100)]:
    y.append(x)
a = Counter(y)
b= a.most_common(1)
print(b)
```

I want to know that number so I need to select it alone. So for example, my output is

```
[(2, 17)]
```

2 is the most frequent number, so how I'm going to select that number from that structure type. Expected output:

```
2
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the top most common, the preferred way is:

```
a = collections.Counter(y)
most_common = max(a, key=a.get)
print(most_common)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

The reason for doing that instead of using [most_common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common), is specified in the documentation of [heap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) (the inner data structure used by Counter):

> The latter two functions perform best for smaller values of n. For
>   larger values, it is more efficient to use the sorted() function.
>   Also, when n==1, it is more efficient to use the built-in min() and
>   max() functions. If repeated usage of these functions is required,
>   consider turning the iterable into an actual heap.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
b= a.most_common(1)[0][0]
```